# Can you play online with a game bought on a none online subscription account in Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online

I currently have two accounts on my switch each connected to the Japan and US e-store. The US account has the Nintendo Online subscription, but the Japanese one doesn't. If I was to buy a game in the Japanese account and play it with my US account, could I use the online feature for that game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the account with Online is using your console as primary by going to the shop and checking in the top right corner, that should let the other use it